$\sum_1^{+\infty} a_j^2 < \infty$ if and only if $\psi_n$ is a Cauchy sequence?
Let  $(\xi_j)_j$ be a complete orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, I want to prove , Given that $\sum_1^{+\infty} a_j^2 < \infty$, the sequence $$\psi_n(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\langle x, \xi_j\rangle -\frac{1}{4} \sum_1^{n} a_j^2 }, \quad x \in \mathbb{S}'$$ is a cauchy sequence in
$L^2(\mathbb{S}',\mu)$ where $(\mathbb{S}',\mu)$ is the white noise probability space .
$\mathbb{S}'$ is the space of tempred distrubition
Hida Brownian motion 1980
PS: the screenshot is taken from Hida book brownian motion 1980

Is $(\mathbb S',\mu)$ aribitrary? Usually you do Hida Calculus on the Schwartz functions (or the corresponding dual space) with the White Noise measure.

Well, $(\mathbb{S}',\mu)$ is the white noise space, but I just want to know how to prove it, Hida in his book said just it's easy and didn't mention anything and I really stuck because in my method ,although I write that $ \sum_{j=1}^n \langle x,\xi_j \rangle^2 < M $, I don't know how to prove it ? or maybe there's another method . If you could give me some idea ? please @Konstruktor

Define $$\mathbb S'\ni \omega\mapsto \psi_n(\omega):=\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j\left\langle \omega, \xi_j\right\rangle-\frac{1}{4} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2\right)\in \mathbb R.$$ It applies for all $n\in \mathbb N$:
\begin{align*}
\|\psi_n\|_{L^2(\mathbb S',\mu)}
&=\exp\left(-\frac14\sum_{j=1}^na_j^2\right)\|\varphi_n\|_{L^2(\mathbb S',\mu)}\\
\end{align*}
for $$\mathbb S'\ni \omega\mapsto \varphi_n(\omega):=\exp\left(-\frac12\sum_{j=1}^na_j\langle \omega,\xi_j\rangle\right)\in \mathbb R.$$
Define $M:=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_j^2\in [0,\infty)$, thus:
$$e^{-\frac14M}\|\varphi_n\|_{L^2(\mathbb S')}\leq \|\psi_n\|_{L^2(\mathbb S')}\leq \|\varphi_n\|_{L^2(\mathbb S')}.$$  Therefore $(\psi_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if $(\varphi_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since the white noise measure has the product property for the ONS $(\xi_j)_j$:
\begin{align*}\|\varphi_n\|_{L^2(\mathbb S',\mu)}^2&=\int_{\mathbb S'}\prod_{i=1}^n\exp\left(-a_j\langle w,\xi_j\rangle\right)\;\text d\mu(\omega)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n\int_{\mathbb S'}\exp\left(-a_j\langle w,\xi_j\rangle\right)\;\text d\mu(\omega)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n\exp\left(-\frac12a_j^2\langle \xi_j,\xi_j\rangle\right)\\
&=\exp\left(-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^na_j^2\right).
\end{align*}
The continuity of the exponential function now ensures the assertion.
I used for the proof that you know: $$\int_{\mathbb S'}e^{\langle \omega, f\rangle}\;\text d\mu(\omega)=e^{\frac12\langle f,f\rangle}$$ for $f\in \mathbb S$. (The proof is quite technical, but straightforward.)
